# What is the difference between KMC 410Z vs 710 chain?

Tags: chain, fixed-gear, single-speed

What is the difference between `KMC 410Z` VS `KMC 710` chain?

For use in single-speed or fixed gear bike.

Comment: Please provide links to the products you are referring to. I could not find a 410 chain on KMCs website.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus, I didn't fined z410 on KMC site.
But it appers on aliexpress (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32874202171.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2afe2120dQLcSQ&algo_pvid=0e163c71-78d9-4144-b532-d662c23d9226&algo_expid=0e163c71-78d9-4144-b532-d662c23d9226-0&btsid=52de446d-ad34-4860-b760-441f973faebf&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_6,searchweb201603_52)

Does it mean, that it's fake?

Comment: It may be that different names or codes are given to different products in different areas, or the 410 is an older product. As far as I can see the [710](http://kmcchain.us/chain/hl710l-green/) is a half link design and the 410 you linked to isn't.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus
710 I found here:
http://kmcchain.us/chain/k710-shiny-green/
 and here 
https://www.kmcchain.eu/chain-bmx_track_fixie-singlespeed-wide-KMC_HL710_Silver

Comment: I love how compatibility picture for KMC 710 at that link lists the chain to be compatible with Shimano, SRAM and Campy but not KMC.

Comment: Straight up from the URLs I see one's a US market product and one's for the EU.

Comment: KMC is a third party brand. Nobody cares about compatibility with them.

Comment: This is impossible to answer - there are a variety of designs that carry the code 710 , including light and half link and strong formats.  I feel this question might be better if you ask about the specifiic design features, like "what is a mushroomed rivet and why would it be a feature ?"

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov To be fair, AFAIK KMC doesn't sell cassettes, cogs, freewheels, derailleurs, cranksets, chainrings, or anything a bicycle chain has to be compatible **with**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 410 series is very basic 1/8" chain. It's one of the most populous single speed chains in the world. There are different color and finish options for it out there.

The 710 series is oversize heavy-duty Street-oriented 1/8" chain with nonstandard/asymmetric outer plates. It's thicker and is purported to have extra-strong riveting.

Comment: I would wish, that KMC manufacturer, had such information on their website.